# Error: flutter instance of 'future string'?

Tags: android, flutter

How do I fix it? It is a flutter authentication error.

> GPT this error: **flutter instance of 'future string'**

This is the code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Auth {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser _user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return _user != null ? _user.uid : null;
  }

  Future<String> currentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser _user = await _auth.currentUser();
    return _user != null ? _user.uid : null;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _auth.signOut();
  }

  Future<void> resetAccount(String email) async {
    await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the line of error code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to avoid **flutter instance of 'future string'?**

I will suggest you use your code like this

```
Future signIn(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseUser _user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    String data = _user != null ? _user.uid : null;
  }
```

or call the sign in method like this

```
_performSignIn(_email, _password){
     signIn(_email, _password).then((data), {
            //data will contains either null or uid
            print(data);

})
```

}